# Calling javascript functions from UIWebView

Tags: javascript, iphone, ios, ipad, uiwebview

I am having some trouble calling a javascript function from UIWebView.

Here is my workflow:

Step 1: Webpage loads in UIWebView

Step 2: User clicks on button in Webpage, which initiates a call to an app function thus -

```
window.location=("native-function-call:getSessionID:"+session);
```

Step 3: location change is intercepted by the app function and sets the sessionID in the app -

```
-(BOOL) webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType
{
NSString *requestString = [[request URL] absoluteString];

if([requestString hasPrefix:@"native-function-call:"])
{
    NSArray *components = [requestString componentsSeparatedByString:@":"];
    NSString *function = [components objectAtIndex:1];
    if([function isEqualToString:@"getSessionID"])
    {
        sessionID = [components objectAtIndex:2];
        [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@%@", @"generateToken(\"",sessionID,@"\")"]];
    }
    if ([function isEqualToString:@"getTokenID"])
    {
        tokenID = [components objectAtIndex:2];

        //do stuff to connect to the session with the token

        NSString *javaScriptRequest = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@%@", @"sendRequest(\"",sessionID,@"\")"];
        [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:javaScriptRequest];
    }
    return NO;
}
return YES;
}
```

Step 4: after the sessionID is set, javascript is called - generateToken(session)

Step 5: in the javascript function, generateToken, the function above is called again, thus -

```
window.location="native-function-call:getTokenID:"+token;
```

Step 6: per the code above, the tokenID created in the javascript is passed to the app. The app then proceeds to call yet another function, called sendRequest(session).

Step 6: a notification is generated and send to another device, which contains the sessionID above. the other device gets the notification, and the function which executes is:

```
-(void) requestReceived:(NSNotification *) pushNotification
{
NSDictionary *notification = [pushNotification userInfo];
sessionID = [notification objectForKey:@"session"];
[webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@%@", @"generateToken(\"",sessionID,@"\")"]];
}
```

Step 7: this is the step that is breaking. per the code above, i am setting debug points, and the last notification function is being entered into on the other device. However, the javascript call to generateToken(session) is not working. The intercept for the location change is never happening, and so the other device is not moving forward with the process.

Any ideas about why that last request is not being sent to the page, or what is breaking? Thank you.

Comment: What do you mean when you say "Step 6: a notification is generated and send to another device, which contains the sessionID above. the other device gets the notification, and the function which executes is:". How are you sending a notification to another device?

Comment: Through APNS. I tell the server to send a notification, and the other device receives the notification with a payload containing the sessionID.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out what was wrong. All the calls to window.location were getting mixed up and some were not executing. I solved the problem by separating the javascript into different server side files and calling each separately instead of making all the calls to the same webview.